# Wordpress - сайт на двух языках

Tags: php, wordpress, локализация

Поставил плагин qTranslate, все прекрасно работает но, язык который выбран не по умолчанию, добавляется приставка /ru/ (http://сайт.ru/ru/). Можно ли например выставить английскую версию для домена com, а для русскоязычной версии ru ? Нужен совет, как это возможно реализовать.

Answer (score 2):

Сделать на сайте по ссылке http://сайт.ru русскоязычную версию. а по http://en.сайт.ru англоязычную допустим и в домене .com настроить CNAME запись которая будет переадресовывать на en.сайт.ru.

Comment: Такой вариант я рассматривал но, мне бы хотелось что бы, по ссылке сайт.com была доступна английская версия сайта, а по сайт.ru была доступна русская версия.